# Laravel, Predis - how to iterate through Hashes

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade, predis

I have set of of hashes

```
taxi:1 p1 v1 p2 v2 ...
taxi:2 p1 v3 p2 v4 ...
taxi:3 p1 v5 p2 v6 ...
taxi:4 p1 v1 p2 v7 ...
```

How do I iterate through them efficiently.

My goal is to display some [cards](http://materializecss.com/cards.html) with data in a Blade template.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in my Controller

```
$arr = [];
//foreach($redis->keys('taxi*') as $t)
    foreach(new Iterator\Keyspace($redis, 'group_location*') as $groupLocation)
{
    $arr[] = $redis->hscan($t,1)[1];
}
```

which returned me what I needed.

However, I have a feeling this is running `count($redis->keys('taxti*'))` calls to the Redis which seems like a thing that should be avoided.